# How to "AcquireToken" for both Microsoft Graph and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I can Get a Valid Token for Graph with a certificate using:

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, certificate);
```

Where

```
resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
```

I can do the same with my SharePoint Online with:

```
resource = "https://{myAAD}.sharepoint.com"
```

I would like to use the same token for both so I tried:

```
resource = "https://{myAAD}.sharepoint.com;https://graph.microsoft.com";
```

It did not work! 
The Tenant, client ID, and the certificate are all the same for both
Is there a way to do it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

An access token is always valid for a single resource, not more.
You simply need to call the AcquireTokenAsync method twice, once for the graph, once for SharePoint.